# Updating a RealmObject with a property of RealmList of Realmobjects error

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I have two classes, Visit and Location. Inside a Visit there can be many locations appended as a property. On the first time I save a specific visit with a new Location added to the locations list everything would work fine, but it would crash the next time I add or remove something from the visit list.

My goal is to have a list that could be manipulated every now and then, but it seems I'm stuck on this issue.

```
class Visit: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String?
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    var locations = List<Location>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

class Location: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String?
    @objc dynamic var address: String?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error below:

```
'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to create an object of type 'Location' with an existing primary key value '071A37EF-A7D3-4190-B535-D74A3B69C2AD'.'
```

---

#### Solved

Solved, the problem with my code was that I was creating the object via realm.create(visit), it was fixed when I've discovered realm.create(visit, update: true)

Comment: So how exactly are you trying to write the `Visit` into Realm when this happens?

Comment: Please show the actual code you use that produces the error.